# Exclude custommodule Js from minification of Js in Magento2

Tags: magento-2.1, javascript, configuration

I am trying to minify JS in `Magento 2`.
There is an option in the Backend: **Stores** -> **Configuration** -> **Advanced** -> **Developer** to minify js. I did that and JS got minified but it also includes my custom module's JS.

It should not include my custom module JS because it contains already minified JS. i want to exclude those JS from minification.

Answer (score 14):

In your custom module, you'll want to add an interceptor to `\Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Minification::getExcludes`, which determines the files to exclude from minification.

Your files would look something like this:

**MODULE/etc/di.xml**  (Be careful! Don't put it in etc/frontend/di.xml, it has to be etc/di.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Minification">
        <plugin name="my-exclude" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\ExcludeFilesFromMinification" />
    </type>
</config>
```

### MODULE/Plugin/ExcludeFilesFromMinification.php

#### Magento < 2.2

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;
use Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Minification;

class ExcludeFilesFromMinification
{
    public function aroundGetExcludes(Minification $subject, callable $proceed, $contentType)
    {
        $result = $proceed($contentType);
        if ($contentType != 'js') {
            return $result;
        }
        $result[] = 'Vendor_Module/js/your-js-filename';
        return $result;
    }
}
```

#### Magento > 2.2

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;
use Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Minification;

class ExcludeFilesFromMinification
{
    public function afterGetExcludes(Minification $subject, array $result, $contentType)
    {
        if ($contentType == 'js') {
            $result[] = 'Vendor_Module/js/your-js-filename';
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer is more conflict proof and should work in all cases

Answer (score 5):

Since Magento 2.3 it is now possible to define additional exclusions via a module's `etc/config.xml` with the following syntax:

```
<config>
    <default>
        <dev>
            <js>
                <minify_exclude>
                    <example1>/example1/</example1>
                </minify_exclude>
            </js>
            <css>
                <minify_exclude>
                    <example2>/example2/</example2>
                </minify_exclude>
            </css>
        </dev>
    </default>
</config>
```

All of these values will now be merged with, instead of overwriting, the previous value.

The pull request for this change can be seen here: https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/13687

Comment: Can you clarify what value needs to go in place of `/example1/`?  is that a directory or file path?  I haven't been able to find documentation on this yet.

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the value of 'dev/js/minify_exclude' on `core_config_data` to a list of ignored scripts (pipe separated).
Note that it's practically a regex pattern that Magento uses in order to exclude scripts from minify.
Therefore, it may look like that for example:

```
https://www.somedomain.com/somescript.js|https://www.another-url.com/anotherscript.js|https://www.blablabla.net/blablabla.js
```

After you do that, you need to flush all caches & pub/static files & re-deploy static-content.

*You may also check the file pub/static/frontend/{Vendor}/{Theme}/{Locale}/requirejs-min-resolver.min.js & see your list in the url.match(...)

Answer (score 1):

For exclude js file from the minify, Add below code in the config.xml file of you extension.

Open or create below file in your custom module.

**EDIT:** app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/config.xml

```
<dev>
    <js>
       <minify_exclude>
          <exclude_name>Vendor_Module/js/filename.js</exclude_name>
        </minify_exclude>
     </js>
</dev>
```

**exclude_name** :- You can change name here whatever you want.

**File Path**:- Pass file path as per the above mentioned.

**Create:** app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <dev>
            <js>
               <minify_exclude>
                  <exclude_name>Vendor_Module/js/filename.js</exclude_name>
                </minify_exclude>
             </js>
        </dev>
    </default>
</config>
```

**Run the below commands.**

php bin/magento c:c

php bin/magento c:f

php bin/magento s:up

php bin/magento s:d:c

php bin/magento s:s:d -f

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This helped for a different [issue](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5835) but it might be useful here...

In your modules config.xml file add the following:

```
<default>
    <dev>
        <js>
            <minify_exclude>
                your-js-filename
            </minify_exclude>
        </js>
    </dev>
</default>
```

Comment: This will _work_ but is a bad solution, as it changes the default setting (which is tiny_mce)

Comment: @Navarr I don't think it does? If I'm correct the values of each minify_exclude xml node are retrieved as an array by \Magento\Framework\App\Config

Comment: @milan it definitely uses scope config, and then just turns lines into an array. https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Asset/Minification.php

Comment: @Navarr I tested it and I can confirm that you're correct. The default tiny_mce value gets overwritten. When multiple modules use this method it will certainly cause conflicts.

Comment: @MilanSimek so you're saying that the out of box Magento 2.2.4 Klarna module could likely be what's breaking my tiny_mce? html/vendor/klarna/module-kp/etc/config.xml:
   45          <dev>
   46              <js>
   47:                 <minify_exclude>
   48                      klarnacdn.net
   49:                 </minify_exclude>
   50              </js>
   51          </dev>

Comment: @Rob that might be the case indeed. My tests showed that Navarr is correct when he pointed out that an interceptor should be used instead of config.xml

Comment: @MilanSimek Thanks!  I confirmed this caused this exact approach was used by the Magento Included Klarna module.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is just to rename you files to end with *.min.js,
Which is good practice, anyway. Magento will recognize the files as already minimized and skip them.