# How to exclude 3rd party JS files from minification?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, javascript, requirejs, minify

I have read these pages below:

- https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5835
- [Exclude custommodule Js from minification of Js in Magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/162624/exclude-custommodule-js-from-minification-of-js-in-magento2/198480#198480)
- https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/13687

and I still don't know how to modify `config.xml` to exclude 3rd party JS files

The module is from an extension by Mageplaza https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-social-share/

[image: error]

The code I add to the module `config.xml` is

```
        <dev>
            <js>
                <minify_exclude>
                    <config>https://static.addtoany.com/menu/page.js</config>
                </minify_exclude>
            </js>
        </dev>
```

Answer (score 1):

Paste this after

> `<default>`

in `config.xml`

```
    <dev>
        <js>
            <minify_exclude>
                <mpsocialshare>https://static.addtoany.com/menu/page.js
                </mpsocialshare>
            </minify_exclude>
        </js>
    </dev>
```

Comment: You are right. Just to be clearer, I included a full answer as to why it initially won't work.

Answer (score 0):

A full answer, all steps below should be done accordingly:

1. Modify the module's `config.xml`, with the following:

```
<config>
    <default>
        <dev>
          <js>
            <minify_exclude>
              <social_share>
                https://static.addtoany.com/menu/page.js
              </social_share>
            </minify_exclude>
          </js>
        </dev>
    </default>
</config>
```

2. remove all relevant `requirejs-min-resolver.min.js` in `pub/static/`, for example:

```
rm pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/requirejs-min-resolver.min.js
```

3. Flush `layout` cache

```
bin/magento cache:flush layout
```

4. Redeploy

```
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US -a frontend -t Magento/luma
```

*note ,after this step, you can check the before and after difference in `pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/requirejs-min-resolver.min.js`*

5. curl or browse your website in a browser for new cached merged minified .js and .css files

```
curl -Lo test.html localhost:/magento
```

*from what I test, you don't have to flush `full_page`, it will generate new .js and .css file nonetheless*

**I have to be specifc, since we are on production mode, clearing everything in `generated/`, `pub/static/` and `var/` will be a waste of time to wait for deployment.**

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the config.xml file of the custom extension (app/code/**Vendor**/**Extension**/etc/config.xml).

Paste the following code in the **default** tag in **config.xml**

```
<dev>
    <js>
        <minify_exclude>
            <mpsocialshare>\.addtoany\.com/menu/</mpsocialshare>
        </minify_exclude>
    </js>
</dev>
```

I suppose to create/update the extension: Endertech_Cms.

So create the files:

1. app/code/Endertech/Cms/**registration.php**

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Endertech_Cms',
    __DIR__
);
```

2. app/code/Endertech/Cms/etc/**module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Endertech_Cms" setup_version="1.1.0">
        <sequence>
            <!-- Endertech Cms needs Magento CMS to be loaded? -->
            <module name="Magento_Cms" />
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

3. app/code/Endertech/Cms/etc/**config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <dev>
            <js>
                <minify_exclude>
                    <mpsocialshare>\.addtoany\.com/menu/</mpsocialshare>
                </minify_exclude>
            </js>
        </dev>
    </default>
</config>
```

Run the following commands to deploy:

```
rm -rf var/di/* var/generation/* var/cache/* var/view_preprocessed/*
php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento setup:upgrade
php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento setup:di:compile
php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento cache:clean
```